# What scifi 70s/80s series featured a 'trivial pursuit' charging station?

Tags: story-identification, buck-rogers

I remember watching a scifi series in the late 80s/early 90s in which one of the bad guys has a power (to shoot rays from his hand?). To recharge his power, he has to put his hand on a multicolored disc (similar to a trivial pursuit thingy). Which series is this?

By browsing YouTube I think it might be Buck Rogers in the 25th Century, but I'm not sure. It does look familiar.

Comment: Instead of Trivial Pursuit, are you thinking of the [Simon game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game))?

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly thinking of [Captain Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)?

The show did have [bad guys who could shoot beams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eAA9rKZc-U&t=15m30s) that would "digitize" their human targets.  As for recharging, it was [the good guys who could power up](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVIQlulvgLY&t=3m30s) at a base station using their hands.